# python socket module in main() unresolved

Tags: python, sockets

Why when I add socket code in top of the function everything work alright, but if I add it main, suddenly socket becomes unresolved reference. I added `import socket` at file header.

UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'socket' where it is not associated with a value

```
def main():
    """
    Preparing socket interface
    """

    log.info("Preparing socket: {} )".format(SOCKET_PATH))
    s = socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    if os.path.exists(SOCKET_PATH):
        os.remove(SOCKET_PATH)
    s.bind(SOCKET_PATH)
    s.listen(5)
    s.settimeout(1)
```

Comment: You have presumably got *import socket* somewhere in your code which makes *s = socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)* a nonsense. How about just *s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)*

Comment: yes, thanks, can't believe I missed that